# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am developing an application with react native. I am able to build the project via Xcode. But when I archive, I encounter the error message I specified. Can you help me?

> **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOg9A.png)

Comment: Did you opened the XCWorkspace and not the xcodeproj? There should be more error explaination message...

Comment: add screenshot of error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.